# Woocommerce warranty does not belong to a user?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im a little surprised..

Im using woocommerce and the wc_warranty class, to my suprise i can se that a warranty dosent belong to a user so i cannot get the warranty history that belong to a logged in user!?!?

I want to be able to fetch a users total warranties that he made by his user_id. I seems that warranties does not belong to a specific user :(

Am i looking att the wrong table?

[image]

Comment: There is no wc_warranty by default in Woocommerce. *"Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."*… It seems that you are using a plugin and you should better contact authors support pages for that.

Comment: Ok! That was what i assumed :) Thanks for the  fast answer!